# Java - send command to FFMPEG process to stop

Tags: java, ffmpeg, command-line, process, processbuilder

I am trying to integrate FFMPEG for screen capture in my program & when the time comes to stop the capture I have to pass 'q' in the commandline to stop the render & save the capture in MP4 file. Unfortunately I am not able to stop FFMPEG & it continues to run in the background. The screenshot below shows FFMPEG running when executed manually via terminal or CMD that q key needs to be passed to halt it.

[image]

Below is my code so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    var processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
    var file = new File("D:\\ffmpeg-5.1-essentials_build\\bin");
    processBuilder.directory(file);
    processBuilder.command("CMD", "/C", "ffmpeg.exe -f gdigrab -i desktop -c:v libx264 -b:v 6000K -minrate 6000K -maxrate 6000K -bufsize 6000K -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 60 -profile:v main -crf 12 -x264-params scenecut=0:open_gop=0:min-keyint=72:keyint=72 -y " +
                    "D:\\Users\\vabali\\Documents\\Workspace\\Captures\\output.mp4");
    var process = processBuilder.start();
    Awaitility.await().atMost(Duration.ofSeconds(5)).until(() -> process.descendants().toList().size() > 1);
    System.out.println("FFMPEG PID = " + process.descendants().toList().get(1).pid());
    var output = process.getOutputStream();
    output.write(KeyEvent.VK_Q);
    output.flush();
    System.out.println(process.descendants().toList().get(1).isAlive());
```

}

I have tried output.write('q'), output.write("q".getBytes()) but nothing has worked so far. Using the destroy method terminates ffmpeg but abnormal termination corrupts the MP4 making it useless. The program has stop graciously. Can someone help me to figure out how to pass q to console to stop the render?

Comment: Might be worth trying: get ffmpeg's pid and run WIndows ```taskkill```  on it with ```ProcessBuilder```

Comment: Already tried taskkill & its the same as destroy() method that causes abnormal termination.

Comment: `q` command should work (tested in console/Python. Can't help you with Java, but when push comes to shove, you can run 2 ffmpeg processes. First one to record and pipe the recorded frames to the second ffmpeg to encode. Killing the first closes the pipe thereby graciously stops the second.

Comment: Wait, something just hit me, try `output.write("q");`

Comment: output.write() method can only accept an integer or a byte array. It does not accept String which is why I was using "q".getBytes() inside the method but alas it did not work.

Comment: That's tricky... Have you tried the ASCII code for `q`? `output.write(113)`

Comment: That did not work either. Process continues to stay in RAM.